# Extrapolate data from Predict function

Tags: formatting, neural-networks

I'm trying to predict the next Close value in the S&P500 index using the following code:

```
data = SemanticImport["http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=00&b=29&c=\
2015&d=10&e=4&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv"]

training = data[[;; 350]];
test = data[[351 ;;]];

p = Predict[training -> "Close", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]
```

I now want to find the predicted value for the 5th of November, but I'm unsure how to format this. I have tried the following, but this returns an error saying that the data is not formatted correctly.

```
p[DateObject[{2016, 11, 05}]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Examining the `FullForm` of `data[[1]]` and checking with the docs of `Predict` leads to `p[<|"Date" -> DateObject[{2016, 11, 05}]|>]`, what yields `226.454`.

Comment: @corey979 Thanks. Also, is there a way to plot the current data along with the predicted data on a graph?

Comment: I'm getting nonsensical outputs, but I'm unfamiliar with `Association` and `Dataset`, so I'll restrain from causing confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of comparing the predicted and true data:

Train the network using the "Date" and "Open" to predict "Close"

```
p = Predict[training[[All, {"Date", "Open", "Close"}]] -> "Close", 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]
```

This shows how well it performs on the training data

```
DateListPlot[{Normal@training[All, {"Date", "Close"}], 
  Normal@training[All, {"Date", "Open"}][All, {"Date", p}]}]
```

[image]

This shows the same for the testing data

```
DateListPlot[{Normal@test[All, {"Date", "Close"}], 
  Normal@test[All, {"Date", "Open"}][All, {"Date", p}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"data", "predicted"}, Top]]
```

[image]